# List item not conforming to padding

Tags: html, css

I am new to html and CSS but I am having an issue where my padding doesn't seem to affect my list item. What I am referring is the top right "post" box seen here:

http://jsfiddle.net/GYcAg/2/embedded/result/

The header has this code:

```
#header { background-color: orange; height: 60px; line-height: 60px; padding:0px 50px; }
```

My question is, why is this not indented 50px to the left like it seemingly should be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because the `#header ul` is `position absolute`. This means that it will ignore its parents padding.

This should fix it

```
#header ul {
   float: right;
   list-style: none outside none;
   position: relative;
}
```

Comment: `position` does not matter if `float` is specified. Only the `float` has an effect.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
#header ul {
    list-style: none outside none;
    position: absolute;
    right: 50px;
    top: 0;
}
```

//right 0 will skip everything

Answer (score 2):

You'll notice that your list item has a **red** `background-color`, whereas the code you think relates to it (what you've posted here) has a background-color of **orange**.

Your post box is an element inside the `#header` element, not the `#header` element itself.

You want to target the `ul` descendant of the `#header`:

```
#header ul { 
  list-style: none; 
  float:right; 
  top: 0; 
  right:50px; /* <- Change this from 0 to 50px */
}
```

[**jsFiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/GYcAg/7/)